# Why using a GPS usb stick increases the latency of my WiFi connection?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, latency, gps

I noticed an increase in the latency (+- 20ms) of my Wifi connection when I'm retrieving in the same time the GPS location of my notebook.
I paid attention to get the location via the GPS usb stick and the GPS usb stick only. I'm not using the wifi routers to retrieve the location.

Do you have an idea that would explain the link between the use of the GPS usb stick and the increase of the latency of the WiFi connection of my notebook?

Comment: You just deleted https://superuser.com/questions/1686120/why-using-the-gps-chip-increases-the-latency-of-my-wifi-connection & replaced 'mobile' with 'notebook'. GPS doesn't work indoors, as already mentioned.

Comment: I am outdoor. The Gps is returning a valid location.
The only problem is the increase in the latency of my WiFi connection. I don't understand the connection between them. I even use an independent thread to make sure it doesn't come from an overloaded thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing inherent to GPS that should cause an increase in Wi-Fi latency.

You will have to troubleshoot this like any other "the presence of one peripheral slows down my other peripheral" problem. Does one peripheral have a piggish driver? Is one peripheral fouling up your USB bus? Is one device disabling interrupts for a long time? etc.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem with a usb drive that I connected via an A-to-C adapter with my device. For some reason only the combination of 3 specific parts lead to the problem: the A-to-C adapter with an SATA-to-USB cable with a specific drive. The same drive only with the SATA-to-USB cable and also with a different drive are not a problem, even the different drive with the A-to-C adapter works after a short time.

The problem that occured: very high WiFi-latency (normally it is about 1-2ms, but with the problem it increases to the tens and often even the hundreds of milliseconds). I assume this is also the reason why timeouts occure sometimes (between the laptop and the router).

The following [article](https://www.zdnet.com/article/usb-3-and-usb-c-devices-can-cause-problems-with-wi-fi-and-bluetooth-connections-but-theres-a-solution/) says that the problem could be related to inferences of USB (3/c) devices/cables if they are not isolated well/poorly made and then emit radio interference in the 2.4GHz frequency range. This problem can be solved (according to the article) by using cables of high quality, switching to 5GHz WiFi (does not work on some older devices, also Bluethoot still would be not working better). The article also lists more options to reduce the problem.

Another possible reason for the problem could be a energy consumption that is too high (i.e. shared power between USB-port and WiFi-card). I came to the conclusion that this could also be the problem as the other drive also increases the latency by very much at the beginning but then settles down to a more reasonable "slowdown".